# Can I use a service like Firebase or Supabase in a Tauri desktop application?

Tags: javascript, firebase, desktop-application, supabase, tauri

I am a full-stack web developer that has experience with JavaScript and React. I want to create a desktop application using these technologies using a framework like Tauri. I enjoy using services like Firebase, Supabase & AWS Amplify. Can I use these services in a desktop application? If so would I implement these services just like any other web application?

Another thing I am confused with is the workflow of desktop applications as I am new to them. Is a backend needed? Or can we access data from a remote DB directly from the desktop application? This approach doesn't seem to be the most secure.

Answer (score 2):

Supabase is built on top of Postgres, so you can use this [postgrest-rs](https://github.com/supabase-community/postgrest-rs) library to access Supabase DB like you would with any Postgres DB. For more complex queries, you can create postgres function(s) in the database and call them using the **rpc** function in the client library.

For more information about other forms of connections, you can have a look at this [guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/connecting-to-postgres).

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about using Supabase Auth and Storage within a Tauri application?

Comment: You would probably have to use the JS library:

https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js

There are some quick start guides for several javascript frameworks that you can use as guidelines including Vue:

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/with-vue-3